# DOJO TreeGrid Child item clickable column

Tags: tree, dojo, grid

I'm working a dojo tree grid and below is the requirement. I want the children of the grid to be clickable columns. Somehow I managed to get the first child of every cell to be a clickable column. But if there are more than one children for a column, either it makes the first or last one clickable under that column. I have attached the picture for your reference and below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dojo/resources/dojo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dojox/grid/resources/soriaGrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css" />
<style type="text/css">
#grid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body clas="claro">

    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
    <div id="gridDiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo/dojo.js"
        data-dojo-config="async:true">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var queues = [ "Cash Room Manager", "Review Check",
                    "Corporate Advanced Manager", "Tax and Insurance Manager",
                    "Sold Loan Manager" ];
        formattohyperlink = function(value, index, items, node, model,
                inRowIndex) {

             for (var i = index; i < node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems.length; i++) {

                var len = node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems[index].children.length;
                console.log("i is "+i +len)
                for (var j = len; j >= 0; j--) {
                console.log("j is now "+j+node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems[index].children)
                console.log(index +node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems[index].children[j-1].step);
                    if (value == node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems[index].children[j-1].step) {
                        return "<a href='#'>" + value + "</a>";
                    } else {
                        return value;
                    }
                }

            } 


        }
        require(
                [ 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/dom-construct', 'dojox/grid/TreeGrid',
                        'dijit/tree/ForestStoreModel',
                        'dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore' ],
                function(dom, domConstruct) {
                    var data = {
                        identifier : 'step',
                        label : 'step',
                        items : [ {
                            step : 'Cash Room',
                            children : [ {
                                step : 'Cash Room Manager',
                                count : '1',
                                inprogress : '21.00',
                                pending : '4555'

                            }, ]
                        }, {
                            step : 'Manual Review',
                            children : [ {
                                step : 'Review Check',
                                count : '1',
                                inprogress : '21.00',
                                pending : '4555'
                            }, ]
                        }, {
                            step : 'Manager Review',
                            children : [ {
                                step : 'Corporate Advanced Manager',
                                count : '1',
                                inprogress : '21.00',
                                pending : '4555'
                            }, {
                                step : 'Tax and Insurance Manager',
                                count : '1',
                                inprogress : '21.00',
                                pending : '4555'
                            }, {
                                step : 'Sold Loan Manager',
                                count : '1',
                                inprogress : '21.00',
                                pending : '4555'
                            }, ]
                        } ]
                    };
                    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
                        data : data
                    });
                    var model = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
                        store : store,
                        childrenAttrs : [ 'children' ]
                    });

                    /* set up layout */
                    var layout = [ {
                        name : 'Step',
                        field : 'step',
                        width : '30%',
                        formatter : formattohyperlink
                    }, {
                        name : 'Count',
                        field : 'count',
                        width : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'In-Progress',
                        field : 'inprogress',
                        width : '20%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Pending',
                        field : 'pending',
                        width : '20%'
                    } ];

                    /* create a new grid: */
                    var grid = new dojox.grid.TreeGrid({
                        id : 'grid',
                        treeModel : model,
                        structure : layout,
                        autoHeight : true,

                    }, document.createElement('div'));

                    /* append the new grid to the div */
                    dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

                    /* Call startup() to render the grid */
                    grid.startup();
                    grid.resize();

                    /* var greetingNode = dom.byId('greeting');
                    domConstruct.place('<i> Manju!</i>', greetingNode);
                    var data = {
                        identifier : 'step',
                        label : 'step',
                        items : [ {
                            name : 'Q1',childern:[
                            count : '1',
                            inprogress : '0',
                            pending : '0',
                            held : '0',
                            warning : '0',
                            deadline : '0',
                            oldestitem : '2016-09-28']

                        } ]
                    };
                    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data:data});
                    var model = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({store:store,childrenAttrs:['childern']});

                    var layout = [ {
                        name : 'Step',
                        field : 'step',
                        width : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Count',
                        field : 'count',
                        widht : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'In-Progress',
                        field : 'inprogress',
                        widht : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Pending',
                        field : 'pending',
                        widht : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Held',
                        field : 'held',
                        widht : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Warning',
                        field : 'warning',
                        widht : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Deadline',
                        field : 'deadline',
                        widht : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Oldest Item',
                        field : 'oldestitem',
                        widht : '30%'
                    } ];


                    var grid = new dojox.grid.TreeGrid({
                    id:'grid',
                    treemodel:model,
                    structure:layout
                    },document.createElement('div'));
                    dojo.byId('lazyTreeGrid').appendChild(grid.domNode);
                    grid.startup(); */

                });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just ignore the commented code please

Comment: I got this working...

Answer (score 0):

Final code. Ignore commented code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dojo/resources/dojo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dojox/grid/resources/soriaGrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css" />
<style type="text/css">
#grid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body clas="claro">

    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
    <div id="gridDiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo/dojo.js"
        data-dojo-config="async:true">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var queues = [ "Cash Room Manager", "Review Check",
                "Corporate Advanced Manager", "Tax and Insurance Manager",
                "Sold Loan Manager" ];
        formattohyperlink = function(value, index, items, node, model,
                inRowIndex) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(value));
            //alert(value.length);
            //console.log(node.grid.getCell(index) + "+++++++++++++++++");
            //console.log(node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems);
            //console.log(node.grid.store._arrayOfAllItems.length);
            //console.log(value);
            //console.log(node.grid.getItem(index).children.length);
            var itemsList;
            /* dojo.forEach(items, function() {
                itemsList += node.grid.store.getValue("name") + " ";
            }); */
            //console.log(node.grid.store.fetchItemsArray());
            for (var k = 0; k < node.grid.store.length; k++) {
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(items[i]));
            }
            //console.log(items[0]);
            var obj = JSON.stringify(items);
            //console.log(obj);
            var array = new Array();
            array.push(obj);
            //console.log(array);
            //console.log(node.grid.store._getItemsArray()[0].children[0].step);
            for (var i = 0; i < node.grid.store._getItemsArray().length; i++) {
                //console.log(node.grid.store._getItemsArray()[i].children[i].step);
            }

            /* alert('yes');
                var currentNode;
                for (var i = 0; i < node.getChildren().length; i++) {
                    currentNode = node.getChildren()[i];
                    alert(currentNode);
                    //this._expandTree(currentNode);
                } */

            //console.log(JSON.stringify(node));
            //alert(JSON.stringify(node));
            //alert(node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems[1].children[1].step);
            //for(var m=0;m<)
            for (var m = 0; m < node.grid.getItem(index).children.length; m++) {

                if (value == node.grid.getItem(index).children[m].step) {
                    //console.log(node.grid.getItem(index).children[m].step +"::: "+value)
                    return "<a href='http://www.google.com'>" + value + "</a>";
                }else{
                console.log(node.grid.getItem(index).children[m].step +"::: "+value)
                }

            }

            for (var m = 0; m < node.grid.getItem(index).children.length; m++) {

                if (value != node.grid.getItem(index).children[m].step) {
                    //console.log(node.grid.getItem(index).children[m].step +"::: "+value)
                    //return "<a href='http://www.google.com'>" + value + "</a>";
                    return value;
                }

            }
            for (var i = index; i < node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems.length; i++) {
                /*  console
                    .log(value
                            + node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems[index].children.length)   */

                //if (value==node.grid.store._arrayOfAllItems[i].children[i].step) {
                //console.log(node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems[index].children.length)
                var len = node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems[index].children.length;
                //console.log("i is "+i +len)
                for (var j = len; j >= 0; j--) {
                    //console.log("j is now "+j+node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems[index].children)
                    //console.log(index +node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems[index].children[j-1].step);
                    /* if (value == node.grid.store._arrayOfTopLevelItems[index].children[j-1].step) {
                        return "<a href='#'>" + value + "</a>";
                    } else {
                        return value;
                    } */
                }

            }

            /*  for (var m = 0; m < queues.length; m++) {

                    if (value == queues[m]) {
                        return "<a href='#'>" + value + "</a>";
                    } else {
                        return value;
                    }
                } */

        }
        require(
                [ 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/dom-construct', 'dojox/grid/TreeGrid',
                        'dijit/tree/ForestStoreModel',
                        'dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore' ],
                function(dom, domConstruct) {
                    var data = {
                        identifier : 'step',
                        label : 'step',
                        items : [ {
                            step : 'Cash Room',
                            children : [ {
                                step : 'Cash Room Manager',
                                count : '1',
                                inprogress : '21.00',
                                pending : '4555',
                                held:'0',
                                warning:'0',
                                deadline:'0',
                                oldestitem:'02/09/2016'


                            }, ]
                        }, {
                            step : 'Manual Review',
                            children : [ {
                                step : 'Review Check',
                                count : '1',
                                inprogress : '21.00',
                                pending : '4555',
                                held:'0',
                                warning:'0',
                                deadline:'0',
                                oldestitem:'02/09/2016'
                            }, ]
                        }, {
                            step : 'Manager Review',
                            children : [ {
                                step : 'Corporate Advanced Manager',
                                count : '1',
                                inprogress : '21.00',
                                pending : '4555',
                                held:'0',
                                warning:'0',
                                deadline:'0',
                                oldestitem:'02/09/2016'
                            }, {
                                step : 'Tax and Insurance Manager',
                                count : '1',
                                inprogress : '21.00',
                                pending : '4555',
                                held:'0',
                                warning:'0',
                                deadline:'0',
                                oldestitem:'02/09/2016'
                            }, {
                                step : 'Sold Loan Manager',
                                count : '1',
                                inprogress : '21.00',
                                pending : '4555',
                                held:'0',
                                warning:'0',
                                deadline:'0',
                                oldestitem:'02/09/2016'
                            }, ]
                        } ]
                    };
                    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
                        data : data
                    });
                    var model = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
                        store : store,
                        childrenAttrs : [ 'children' ]
                    });

                    /* set up layout */
                    var layout = [ {
                        name : 'Step',
                        field : 'step',
                        width : '30%',
                        formatter : formattohyperlink
                    }, {
                        name : 'Count',
                        field : 'count',
                        width : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'In-Progress',
                        field : 'inprogress',
                        width : '20%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Pending',
                        field : 'pending',
                        width : '20%'
                    } ,{
                        name : 'Held',
                        field : 'held',
                        width : '20%'
                    } ,{
                        name : 'Warning',
                        field : 'warning',
                        width : '20%'
                    } ,{
                        name : 'Deadline',
                        field : 'deadline',
                        width : '20%'
                    } ,{
                        name : 'Oldest Item',
                        field : 'oldestitem',
                        width : '20%'
                    } ];

                    /* create a new grid: */
                    var grid = new dojox.grid.TreeGrid({
                        id : 'grid',
                        treeModel : model,
                        structure : layout,
                        autoHeight : true,

                    }, document.createElement('div'));

                    /* append the new grid to the div */
                    dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);
                    grid.onRowClick = function() {
                        console
                                .log("Rwo is _________________________________________________________________________");
                    };
                    /* Call startup() to render the grid */
                    grid.startup();
                    grid.resize();

                    /* var greetingNode = dom.byId('greeting');
                    domConstruct.place('<i> Manju!</i>', greetingNode);
                    var data = {
                        identifier : 'step',
                        label : 'step',
                        items : [ {
                            name : 'Q1',childern:[
                            count : '1',
                            inprogress : '0',
                            pending : '0',
                            held : '0',
                            warning : '0',
                            deadline : '0',
                            oldestitem : '2016-09-28']

                        } ]
                    };
                    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data:data});
                    var model = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({store:store,childrenAttrs:['childern']});

                    var layout = [ {
                        name : 'Step',
                        field : 'step',
                        width : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Count',
                        field : 'count',
                        widht : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'In-Progress',
                        field : 'inprogress',
                        widht : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Pending',
                        field : 'pending',
                        widht : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Held',
                        field : 'held',
                        widht : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Warning',
                        field : 'warning',
                        widht : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Deadline',
                        field : 'deadline',
                        widht : '30%'
                    }, {
                        name : 'Oldest Item',
                        field : 'oldestitem',
                        widht : '30%'
                    } ];


                    var grid = new dojox.grid.TreeGrid({
                    id:'grid',
                    treemodel:model,
                    structure:layout
                    },document.createElement('div'));
                    dojo.byId('lazyTreeGrid').appendChild(grid.domNode);
                    grid.startup(); */

                });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```